# what type of pages link in php is better?

Tags: url, seo

i want to write a script in php and thats pages and posts url is thats pages and post ID.
for example one of post ID is 123.
we have two type url
1.example.com/?id=123
2.example.com/id/123
this 2 type url have difference in seo and security? or both of them are equal in seo and security?

Comment: Note that asking for SEO advice is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Query String parameters can pose a risk if they are not used properly (e.g. sending sensitive data or `HTML` injection of the query strings). In your case you are using them as a page id.  If a malicious user inputs other values your server will simply return an `HTTP 404`.

They can also have some SEO pitfalls.  [Here](https://www.hallaminternet.com/avoiding-the-seo-pitfalls-of-url-parameters/) is an article that explains some of the issues.  If your site can handle the second type (example.com/id/123) then go that route.